# How much amount of storage is required for storing integers like 1, 11, 111, 1111 individually?

Tags: database, postgresql, int, size, storage

I know that the storage size of 'int' is 4 bytes in postgre, but I want to know how much amount of storage is required for storing integers like 1, 11, 111, 1111 individually when they are inserted to a column of type int. I mean what is the amount of storage required for storing integer 1 and amount of storage required for storing integer 11 and so on.

Comment: An `int` is four bytes. The value is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will store 4 bytes.

The value can be anything from `-2147483648` to `2147483647`.

You can take a look from here: [Postgresql Data Types](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_data_types.htm)